# What is the position topic I should give move base when amcl is not used

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using move base without amcl since I cannot use a predetermined map.  The issue I am having is providing move_base with a position topic since from what I can tell, AMCL provides the robots position. Instead I am using aprilTags position but I don't know what topic and message type to remap the aprilTag position message to so that move base can use it. I have transforms from map->odom->base_link->kinect2_link->kinect2_ir_optical_fram->camera_depth_frame set up already and can visualize that in rviz. (I set map odom and baselink to the same frame ie. the transform is 0,0,0,1) the kinect depth scan to laserscan is working nicely and the costmap is generating.

Any help would be appreciated!
I am running ros kinetic, ubuntu 16.04 on an Intel NUC

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289584/what-is-the-position-topic-i-should-give-move-base-when-amcl-is-not-used/) by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay so the transform between odom and base_link is generated by the [odom](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) tutorial so I removed it from my transform publisher and it was able to work. pretty dumb mistake but move_base is confusing. I am going to insert into the Odometry node the remap from the aprilTag position topic to the odom position topic.

---

Originally posted by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) with karma: 20 on 2018-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-25**:
Please just accept your own answer (tick the checkmark to the left of it) instead of closing a question.